# LocalDB C# некорректно отображает данные при редактировании

Tags: c#, sql, .net

Создаю простое приложение при помощи средств конструктора(программного кода минимум, осваиваю среду). Задача приложения это:
Вывести данные из базы LocalDB(с учётом внешнего ключа) на одной вкладке tabControl, а так же позволить их редактировать на второй.

1. Создаю проект с tabControl
2. Создаю базу данных путём Проект > Добавить > Создать элемент
3. Добавляю таблицы:

   ```
    CREATE TABLE [dbo].[sotrud]
        (
            [id] INT NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY, 
            [surname] NVARCHAR(50) NULL, 
            [name] NVARCHAR(50) NULL, 
            [otch] NVARCHAR(50) NULL, 
            [dolj] NVARCHAR(50) NULL
        )
   ```

А так же таблицу с внешним ключом.

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[opisanie]
    (
    [id] INT NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY, 
    [vozrast] NVARCHAR(50) NULL, 
    [staj] NVARCHAR(50) NULL, 
    [id_sotrud] INT NULL, 
    CONSTRAINT [FK_Table_Tosotrud] FOREIGN KEY ([id_sotrud]) REFERENCES [sotrud]([id])
    )
```

4. Подключаю базу данных как новый источник данных и разворачиваю её на вкладке "Data Source"
   [image: введите сюда описание изображения]
5. Переношу таблицу на форму в виде DataGridView

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

6. Меняю в выпадающем окне таблиц параметр "DataGridView" на "Сведения" и так же перетаскиваю их на форму но уже на вторую вкладку tabControl. При этом компонент BindingNavigator автоматически не создаётся, поэтому я дважды копирую его с первой вкладки

[image: введите сюда описание изображения][image: введите сюда описание изображения]

7. Меняю свойство BindingSource для компонентов BindingNavigator в соответствии с таблицами

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

8. Открываю конструктор баз данных и меняю свойства полей "id" во всех таблицах на:

```
 

    Autoincrement       - True
    AutoincrementSeed   - 1
    AutoincrementStep   - 1
```

В итоге при тестировании программы, первая таблица(Сотрудники) заполняется без нареканий и претензий, а вторая выдаёт просто чудеса.

1. Может связать данные совсем не с тем id которое необходимо.
2. Может просто не внести данные(возможно потому что id к которому она хотела подключиться не существует)
3. В случае если добавить 1 запись и сразу же добавить вторую запись, то первая запись будет нормально отображаться в базе на первой вкладке TabControl.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Подскажите пожалуйста в чем заключается ошибка и как её исправить. Желательно средствами конструктора. Если исправить данную проблему возможно только кодом, то пожалуйста опишите подробно как это сделать, поскольку уровень знаний намного ниже среднего и простой комментарий по типу: "Это ерунда, откомпиль спарси продиспель компонент класса" мне вряд ли поможет. Заранее огромное спасибо!

Comment: Визуальные конструкторы тем и плохи, что сложно вникать в суть проблемы по скриншотам. / По-моему, проблема в наличии трёх `BindingNavigator`. Он должен быть один. Когда на первом `tabPage1` нажимаете плюсик (добавить), должна открываться вторая `tabPage2`, где можно ввести данные новой записи. На ней не должно быть элементов управления. / Имхо, сама идея использования вкладок для ввода новой записи как-то сомнительна.

Comment: @AlexanderPetrov, а есть какая-нибудь альтернатива конструктору в этом плане? Есть ли возможность узнать программный код элементов навигатора чтоб продублировать его на кнопки и таким образом решить проблему? Я понимаю что необходимо указать путь к бд и понимаю где его достать, но вот синтаксически пример бы не помешал. И спасибо огромное за ваш ответ)

Answer (score 0):

Собственно выходные прошли и со свежей головой решить данную проблему оказалось просто, настолько просто что даже стыдно. Дам ответ, вдруг кому из страдальцев вроде меня пригодится.
При создании таблиц или полей заполнения таблиц с помощью конструктора, среда автоматически создаёт `BindingNavigator` в котором помимо стандартных компонентов находится кнопка сохранения/обновления - [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

И вот в отличии от стандартных элементов она содержит код который возможно отобразить. При копировании `BindingNavigator`, для корректной работы требуется не только изменить свойство `BindingSource`, но и заполнить кнопку сохранения/обновления([image: введите сюда описание изображения]) программным кодом аналогичным тому который будет создан автоматически с первой навигационной панелью.

Извиняюсь за заданные глупые вопросы.